# res folder inside bin has gone empty,causing errors.How to fix?Something to do with options menu?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, project-management, options-menu

The res folder inside of bin is supposed to contain .dex,.apk and .ap_ i think.Mines gone empty somehow causing errors like not being able to access the layout resources.I have tried clean and build but it doesent seem to work.Just seem to create an empty res folder.So any idea how to fix this?
Thanks.

Ok my problem is with an xml file i'm creating inside of res/menu inorder to create an options menu:
options.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu> 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
android:id="@+id/setmenu"
android:title="@string/settings"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"></item>
<item
android:id="@+id/helpmenu"
android:title="@string/help"
androidLicon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"></item>
</menu>
```

Heres the error i am getting:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   TriviaQuiz      line 1  Android ADT Problem

Console Messages:
[2011-11-19 16:47:24 - TriviaQuiz] W/ResourceType( 4672): Bad XML block: header size 116 or total size 7602372 is larger than data size 0
[2011-11-19 16:47:24 - TriviaQuiz] H:\workspace\TriviaQuiz\res\menu\options.xml:5: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Any idea what it is.

Comment: This is more like the result of an error instead of causing errors. Most likely you have made an error in your layout/resource files that prevents auto-generation of these files. Check everything you edited since your last successfull build for mistakes. When you fixed these, everything should be fine again. - EDIT: Also check the "Problems" tab in eclipse, maybe theres a hint in there whats wrong.

Comment: check you might have created a resource file with capital letters in their file name. it can be a cause. which sometime dont show up easily

Comment: Updated the post with problem details.

Comment: Ok i fixed the problem.Was problem with the xml file.Had put a wrong '>' at the start of menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that an error in one of my resources (usually a layout) causes this. Missing quotes or /> in particular are a good starting point - that's my personal blind spot and eclipse punishes it mercilessly!

As alextsc says, check everything you edited recently.

Comment: if answer is not specific try posting things as a comment. it will be helpful for others if following this question and its answer

Comment: For this issue and without the full source code checking layout files is probably about as specific as an answer can get and it does at least give shady an answer to accept if it solves the problem (something you can't do with a comment). Point taken, however.

Comment: Updated the post with problem details